# How to create proper regex

Tags: c#, java, php, regex

I'm new with this function, but I think it is exactly what I need for a specific field validation.  How do I allow only the following characters with spaces or carriage return on a `textarea`:

```
Allowed chars: 
numbers: 0 to 9
alpha: R L F Y
chars: , - (comma and dash)
```

I also need it so that the validated field can either start with the numbers or the alpha but not the comma (`,`) or dash (`-`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Do you do this using JavaScript or the server-side language (which?)? And what have you tried? Have you checked out [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Comment: @Learner, where did you take the tags C#, Java and PHP from?

Comment: In a comment to an answer here you wrote that `RLF` must be always in that order. I think you need to edit your question to specify *exactly*  what's allowed and what isn't. Perhaps provide some examples that are legal/illegal. Also, please answer @m.buettner's question.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
/^\s*[RFLY0-9][RFLY0-9,\-\s]*$/
```

Obviously, dependent on the unspecified regex parser you are using.

**Edit:**
Added spaces.

Comment: Also does not allow an empty string.

Comment: I think I just found it. this seems to work: /^\s*[RFLY0-9][RFLY0-9,\-\s]*$/

Comment: Will keep testing different sets, but I think this is it.  Thanks so much for the immediate responses!

Comment: That looks like my answer. Please accept me @user1826037

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/[0-9RLFY\-\,]/
```

You could add other chars in the brackets and could add 'i' modifier at the end for 'ignore case'

Comment: `Y-,` is not a valid range and will either cause an error or be ignored - either way, the dash won't be part of the character class

Comment: tried that and the other post above. does not work. it does not allow me to enter RLF as the first set of chars.  the typical value sets that can be entered are RLF,100,101- or 10Y,11Y,RLF,100,200,201-,300

Comment: Sorry if I was not too clear with how the values can be entered. The 3 chars RLF, if opted to be entered must be in that order - RLF. The Y char is always added at the end of a num char and will never have a dash char added with it.

Comment: could you supply some samples?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-9RLFY][0-9RLFY,\-\s]$/
```

should do the trick. Depending on what kind of white spaces you want, replace the `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this pattern:

```
^[0-9RLFY]([0-9RLFY\-\,]*)|\s*$
```

Make it case insensitive as per the need using `?i` modifier.